# GNP v. GDP as a true measure of national vibrancy

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp

Is the GNP a more realistic number or measure of national economic vitality regarding its citizenry/residents of the nation in question versus the GDP?

Comment: What do you mean by economic vitality?

Comment: of "national" economic : you answered your own question...

Answer (score 1):

What used to be called GNP is now called *Gross National Income* (GNI) as being more descriptive of what it is measuring.

So GDP measures what is produced in a year while GNI measures incomes in a year, with the difference being some cross-border flows of money unrelated to exports and imports of goods and services.

Personally I prefer GDP as it reflects what is happening in a country, but it depends on what you regard as *vitality*.

Answer (score 1):

GNP (Gross national product) measures all of incomes of every citizen in a country. This means that if I as a citizen have a business outside of my home country my income from that business still applies to the GNP. GDP, which is the more common measure is the measure of all economic activity within a country's borders. Meaning that my income from my foreign company would not be counted towards GDP.

GDP is generally used as the standard for economic activity because it provides a good look into what is going on within a country's borders, without potentially inflating economic activity of a country by looking at foreign investments.